# Equivalent measures if integral of $C_b$ functions is equal

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Is it true that if $X$ is a measure space and $\mu, \nu$ are Borel probability measures on $X$ if 
$$ \int_X \phi \ d \mu = \int_X \phi \ d \nu \qquad \forall \phi \in C_b(X) \text{ (continuous and bounded functions)} $$
then $$ \mu = \nu  \text{ ?}$$

If $E$ is a measureable set s.t. $1_E \in C_b(X)$ then $\mu(E) = \nu(E)$, but if it's not?

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space?

Comment: Yes if it's needed. Does it changes the situation?

Comment: It makes the things simpler, as you can approximate pointwise the characteristic function of a closed set by continuous bounded functions. You can also do that in topological spaces with a condition of separation (Urysohn lemma will help).

Comment: In a metric space, could I work it out saying that the characteristic function $1_E$ is lower semicontinuous, so I can find an approximation with continuous functions $f_n$ s.t. $ \sup f_n = 1_E$ and then use the monotone convergence theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $\left(X,d\right)$ is a metric space and let $F$ be a closed subset of $X$. For $S\subset X$ and $x\in S$, define $d(x,S):=\inf\{d(x,y),y\in S\}$.

Let $O_n:=\left\{x\in X,d(x,F)<n^{-1}\right\}$. Then $O_n$ is open and the map $$f_n\colon x\mapsto \frac{d\left(x,X\setminus O_n\right)}{d\left(x,X\setminus O_n\right)+d\left(x,F\right)}$$ is continuous and bounded. It converges pointwise and monotonically to the characteristic function of $F$. So we get by monotone convergence that $\mu(F)=\nu(F)$ for all closed set $F$.

Now given a Borel set $B$ and $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a closed set $F$ and an open set $O$ such that $F\subset S\subset O$ and $\mu(O\setminus S)\leqslant\varepsilon$. Conclude.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after such a long time, but your maps $f_n$ seem wrong. For instance, they are ill-defined for points $x \in F$, since both $d(x, O_n)$ and $d(x,F)$ are zero. They don't seem to go to $0$ for points outside $F$ either.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. You are right, there was a mistake in the definition of $f_n$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It's never too late! Your answer was very helpful to me. It seems that the result might still be true if the hypothesis held only for compacty supported continuous functions. One would consider a compact set instead of the closed $F$, and the $f_n$ would then be compactly supported. But we would need to approximate any Borel set from the inside by compact sets... is this always possible or do we need additional assumptions on the measures?

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Maybe the assumption would also be in the metric space. If it is separable and complete, or if it can be expressed as a countable union of compact set, then we can approximate any Borel set from the inside by compact sets (this is called by some authors "inner regularity").

Answer (score 0):

Indicator functions are not continuous. One can use Urysohn's lemma. For a closed subset $E$ and a closed closed subset $ D\subseteq E^{c}$, we construct a bounded continuous function $f$, which is 1 on E and zero on D. If $u(E)-v(E)=c>0$, we need $\int _{E^{c}/D}fdv-\int _{E^{c}/D}fdu=c$. However, since u and v are regular we can choose D such that $\left|\int _{E^{c}/D}fdv-\int _{E^{c}/D}fdu  \right|\leq v\left (E^{c}/D  \right )+u\left (E^{c}/D  \right )\leq \frac{c}{2}$. That is to say u and v agree on all closed subsets. The rest is a standard conlusion from Dynkin's theorem.