# Equality of Measures and Intuition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Caveat: I have no formal training in measure theory and am learning as I go.

The concept in this question is puzzling me:

[Equivalent measures if integral of $C_b$ functions is equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334251/equivalent-measures-if-integral-of-c-b-functions-is-equal)

I'll re-state the idea here:

> If $X$ is a measure space and $\mu, \nu$ are Borel probability measures on $X$, then if 
>   $$ \int_X \phi \ d \mu = \int_X \phi \ d \nu \qquad \forall \phi \in C_b(X) \text{ (continuous and bounded functions)} $$
>   then $$ \mu = \nu  \text{ .}$$

Perhaps I misunderstood the answer, but it seems to affirm this statement. But I don't understand the intuition here.

Imagine $X$ is just a subset of the reals with the Borel sigma algebra. If $\phi$ is just the identity function, i.e. $\phi(x) = x$, then the above statement implies that if two means are equal then the probability measures are equal. Clearly I am missing something.

Can someone explain the intuition behind this statement?

Comment: The equality of integrals must hold for **all** continuous and bounded functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\phi(x)=x$ is not a bounded function in general (for example $X=\mathbb{R}$).

But even if it would be a bounded function, then the statement would **not** imply

$$\int_X x \, d \mu(dx) = \int_X x \, d \nu(dx) \Rightarrow \mu = \nu .$$
 The statement says that if
$$ \int_X \phi(x) \, d\mu(x) = \int_X \phi(x) \, d\nu (x) $$
holds for **all** bounded, continuous functions then the measures are equal.

Checking it only for one single function is not enough.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. It's much clearer now.