# Borel functional calculus on reduced von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $M$ be an von Neumann algebra, $x\in M_+$ is a positive element, $e\in M$ is a projection ($e^2=e,e^*=e$). $f$ is a bounded Borel function on spectral set $\sigma(x)$ and $f(0)=0$. If $exe = x$, prove that $f(x)\in eMe$.

My attempt: I know that $f(x) \in M$ by Borel functional calculus, but on the reduced von Neumann algebra $eMe$, we can't say that $f(x)\in eMe$, because the spectral set $\sigma(x)$ in $M$ is different from spectral set in $eMe$ even if $exe=x$. I think that $0\notin \sigma(exe)$ but may be belongs to $\sigma(x)$. so this is why we need that $f(0)=0$, but I don't know how to use this condition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to re-do the Borel functional calculus on $eMe$. All you need is the assertion that $f(x)\in eMe$.

Since $exe=x$, for any $n\in\mathbb N$
$$
x^n=x\,x^{n-1}=exe\,x^{n-1}=e\,exe\,x^{n-1}=ex^n. 
$$
Do the same on the right, or take adjoints, and $x^n=ex^ne$. Thus $p(x)=ep(x)e$ for any polynomial $p$ with $p(0)=0$. The continuous functional calculus then gives you
$$\tag1
f(x)=ef(x)e,\qquad f\in C(\sigma(x))\ \text{ such that $f(0)=0$}. 
$$A typical way to construct the spectral measure for $x$ is to define, for each $\xi\in H$,
$$\tag2
f\longmapsto \langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle. 
$$
This is a bounded positive linear functional on $C(\sigma(x))$, and so by Riesz-Markov there exists a regular Borel measure $\mu_\xi$ on $\sigma(x)$ such that
$$\tag3
\langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(x)}f\,d\mu_\xi,\qquad f\in C(\sigma(x)).
$$
For $f$ bounded Borel, one defines an operator $f(x)\in M$ by
$$
\langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(x)}f\,d\mu_\xi. 
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(3)$ one gets that  $\mu_{e\xi}(\Delta)=\mu_\xi(\Delta)$ for all $\xi\in H$, as long as $0\not\in\Delta$ (since they agree on all continuous $f$ with $f(0)=0$). Then, as long as $f$ is bounded Borel with $f(0)=0$,
$$
\langle ef(x)e\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle f(x)e\xi,e\xi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\}}f\,d\mu_{e\xi}=\int_{\sigma(x)\setminus\{0\}}f\,d\mu_{\xi}=\langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle, 
$$
which shows that $f(x)=ef(x)e\in eMe$.

Comment: Thank you! Why polynomial with $p(0)=0$ could approach continuous function with $f(0)=0$ ？And if we want to use continuous functional calculus, we could directly use it, why we need to prove equation for polynomial with $p(0)=0$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with your first question; you want to approximate a continuous $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ with polynomials that take what value at $0$? As for your second question, if you know that $f(x)=ef(x)e$ then yes, you can use continuous functional calculus directly.

Comment: I don't understand why if $ep(x)e=p(x)$ for $p(0)=0$, then $ef(x)e=f(x)$ for $f(0)=0$? because continuous functional calculus ? But on $M$, we can use it for any  continuous functions because there exist unit in $M$. We don't need $f(0)=0$. Or because continuous functions could be approximated by polynomial? But function take value $0$ at $0$ could be approximated by polynomial take value $0$ at $0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow what you say. If $f(0)\ne0$, then $ef(x)e\ne f(x)$, so I'm not sure where you are going. If $f(0)=0$, then it can be written as a uniform limit of polynomials $p_n$ with $p_n(0)=0$. Then $$\|ef(x)e-f(x)\|\leq \|ef(x)e-ep_n(x)e\|+\|p_n(x)-f(x)\|\leq2\|p_n(x)-f(x)\|\to0, $$ so $ef(x)e=f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I know continuous function can be approximated by polynomials (Weierstrass theorem), but I used to think that if $f(0)=0$, then $p_n$ may be not satisfy $p_n(0)= 0$. Now I know that because $f$ is a uniform limit, then $p(0)$ must be $0$.

Comment: It doesn't have to be zero, but it has to go to zero, which allows you to actually tweak the $p_n$ so that $p_n(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, and I want to ask another question: In the answer you don't use Borel functional calculus directly, right ?

Comment: Up to $(2)$ it is continuous functional calculus, and it is Borel functional calculus after that. I wrote some details partly because I had to remind myself on how it's done, and partly to see how to use the fact that $f(0)=0$ and that $eg(x)e=g(x)$ for continuous $g$ with $g(0)=0$.

Comment: OK! Thank you so much for responding patiently to me.

Comment: Can I ask another question? why $\mu_{\xi}(\bigtriangleup)=\mu_{e\xi}(\bigtriangleup)$, because $f$ is continuous but not measurable? so we can not let $f$ be the  characteristic function of $\bigtriangleup$. 
 I saw such an answer, but i think $\mu_{\xi}(\sigma(x)) \ne \mu_{e\xi}(\sigma(x))$https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334251/equivalent-measures-if-integral-of-c-b-functions-is-equal

Comment: If two regular Borel measures agree on all continuous functions, then they agree. And, as $f(x)=ef(x)e$, $$\int_{\sigma(x)}f\,d\mu_\xi=\langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle ef(x)e\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle f(x) e\xi,e\xi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(x)}f\,d\mu_{e\xi}.$$

Comment: “If two regular Borel measures agree on all continuous functions, then they agree.” Could you tell me which book I can find the proof?  I understand the equaltion of integral, but I can not prove the equation of measure.

Comment: It's the uniqueness in Riesz-Markov, so I assume it should be in most measure theory books.

Comment: But two functional is not same, on the point zero, they may be not equal. I think you used Riesz-Markov twice in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you are saying. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express it clearly. I think the existence of measure $\mu_{e\xi}$ is form functional $f\longmapsto \langle f(x)e\xi,e\xi\rangle$ by Riesz-Markov. This functional is different from the functional $f\longmapsto \langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle$ at $0$ point. so I think even we have (1), we should use Riesz-Markov twice, then we can not use uniqueness.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Both expressions are exactly the same, under your assumptions. What's "0 point"?

Comment: (1) in answer only hold for $f\in C(\sigma(x))$ sucht that $f(0)=0$, not all continuous function$f$. then $$
\int_{\sigma(x)}f\,d\mu_{\xi}=\langle f(x)\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle ef(x)e\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle f(x)e\xi,e\xi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(x)}f\,d\mu_{e\xi},
$$ only hold for continuous functions such that $f(0)=0$, not all.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. That's why I wrote in the answer "as long as $0\not\in\Delta$". You can use RM on $C_0(\sigma(X)\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: Oh, we can directly use RZ on $C_0({\sigma(x)\setminus \{0\}})$, but is there one to one correspondence between $f\in C(\sigma(x))$ such $f(0)=0$ and $g\in C_0({\sigma(x)\setminus \{0\}})$?

Comment: Yes, there is. $ $

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem that has troubled me for a long time, you are so enthusiastic, thank you! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)